# php export data with accents into csv

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

I have the following code that creates a csv file:

```
$data=array();
array_push($data,"Société"); //word with french accent


header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"');


$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, array_map('utf8_decode',array_values($val)), ',', '"');
}
fclose($fp);
```

However when I open the csv file, the character `é` is replaced by a question mark `?`.

Any help how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `UTF-8` characters in the string. I replaced

```
array_push($data,"Société"); //word with french accent
```

with

```
array_push($data,"Soci\xc3\xa9t\xc3\xa9"); //word with french accent
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried removing the **"utf8_decode"** argument in your array_map call ?

If you call the function **"utf8_decode" on a UTF-8 string**, it will return it under **LATIN-1 encoding which doesn't support accents**.

See the PHP documentation of utf8_decode > http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Bon courage.

Comment: I have replaced the line by `fputcsv($fp, $val);` and it still does not show correctly when I open the resulting file in OpenOffice.

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar problem a while ago, I fixed it by adding the 3 byte UTF8 representation before any csv line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export-'.time().'.csv"');

echo chr(0xEF);
echo chr(0xBB);
echo chr(0xBF);
```